# Hashmap creation performance when I know the final number of elements

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

if I know the final size of the elements in a HashMap what is the best way to construct it from a performance point of view? Based on the JavaDoc in order to avoid rehashing the following would do:

```
int TOTAL_ELEMENTS_TO_BE_STORED = 10;
... = new HashMap<T, Q>( TOTAL_ELEMENTS_TO_BE_STORED + 1, 1.0f );
```

but also:

```
... = new HashMap<T, Q>( Math.ceil(TOTAL_ELEMENTS_TO_BE_STORED * 1.333) + 1 );
```

I read from the HashMap javadoc:

> Higher values decrease the space overhead but increase the lookup cost (reflected in most of the operations of the HashMap class, including get and put).

Is it true the lookup cost will be higher? In such a case, is it generally advised to go with the default 0.75 load factor but instead give larger capacity or the converse?

Comment: Microbenchmark it :-) We usually go with your first approach and it is fast enough. The methods in the `Math` package sometimes had some quirky performance issues in our environment.

Comment: If your total size is 10, you really don't need to care. Just use new HashMap<>(). If the number is large, here's how Guava implements it: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/src-html/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#line.289

Comment: Did the default option become too slow already? I think knuth wrote that early optimization is the root of all evils

Comment: Upvoted the comment for the Guava link. Certainly 10 was used for illustration only.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the lookup cost will be higher.

The choice depends on your requirements.

- You need to be able to lookup elements quickly, and your data are small enough - leave 0.75 load factor
- You have a big amount of data and you don't want to spare a lot of memory - use 1.0 as the load factor.

BTW, load factors are not in range [0.75, 1] - you can pick any positive value. The more value is, the less memory you need, but the longer your lookups will be.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is about performance and you know the number of elements in advance, it could be better to choose a hash table with [**open addressing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Open_addressing) (self-written or from some library), but not a standard `HashMap`.

With the small number of elements, a simple `ArrayList` could be faster than any hash table data structure. You need to do some benchmarks.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that is the most expensive is the `resizing` phase of the internal array that is used for the storage. Entries at that point need to be re-hashed and potentially moved to different buckets. While re-sizing can happen for some other reasons also; avoiding the obvious one is a good option.

If you know how many entries you will have, just add 33% to that number and leave the default `load_factor` of `0.75`.

For example, when you have 16 buckets, you can only put 12 entries before the resize happens.

Also the size of the array is the next `power of two` - even if you do not provided as such. So if you have 100 entries; 125 is `+33%`; while internally size is going to be `128`.

Comment: Do you mean +33% ? Then `(MAX_ELEMENTS * 1.33 * 0.75) = MAX_ELEMENTS`

Comment: @user1485864 yes... my bad; so when you know you will have 12 elements, you need to specify the capacity as 16.